# Underscore sortBy, groupBy with count of grouped arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm having a bit of trouble manipulating an array of objects using underscore.  I am almost there but have got stuck on attempting to combine countBy within the underscore chain.

I have the following array of objects (simplified):

```
var messages = [
{
    id: 20,
    messageHeaderId: 6,
    content: "Message 1",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T12:34:49.403974",
    sender: "Diane"
},
{
    id: 22,
    messageHeaderId: 6,
    content: "Latest message from MH6",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T12:38:49.403974",
    sender: "Diane"
},
{
    id: 13,
    messageHeaderId: 5,
    content: "Message 1 from MH5",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T10:34:23.848459",
    sender: "Ora"
},
{
    id: 14,
    messageHeaderId: 5,
    content: "Latest message from MH5",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T12:37:12.237183",
    sender: "Ora"
},

{
    id: 15,
    messageHeaderId: 5,
    content: "Message 2 from MH5",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T11:00:35.547921",
    sender: "Ora"
},

{
    id: 16,
    messageHeaderId: 5,
    content: "Message 3 from MH5",
    dateOfMessage: "2017-08-16T11:36:51.828447",
    sender: "Ora"
}
];
```

My goal is to return just the latest message in each thread, identified by the messageHeaderId, along with the count of messages in the thread as a new array of objects.

So from the array above this would result in an array of 2 objects that have a count property of the number of messages in each group after the groupBy method and added as a property to the returned latest messages.

This is the method I am using to sort and group the array (I'm not sure if having 2 map functions is a good idea(?) but this was the only way I managed to get this far):

```
var selectedMessages = _.chain(messages)
.sortBy('dateOfMessage')
.reverse()
.groupBy('messageHeaderId')
.map(function(a) {return a[0]}) // return latest message in thread
.map(function(b){
    return {
        content: b.content,
        dateOfMessage: b.dateOfMessage,
        headerId: b.messageHeaderId
        // count: ??
    }
})
.value();

console.log(selectedMessages);
```

This gives me the latest message in the thread as a new array of objects and I am just missing the count property.  I have tried various combinations of _.countBy I am just not sure how to get that into the returned array.

I have created a jsfiddle here with the above code:  https://jsfiddle.net/xsfs0ua0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the count after the `groupBy`, but before the first `map` completes, because in that map you're returning *only one record*.

I've modified the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xsfs0ua0/1/

Here's the relevant change:

```
var selectedMessages = _.chain(messages)
    .sortBy('dateOfMessage')
    .reverse()
    .groupBy('messageHeaderId')
    .map(function(a) {
        // since returning only a[0], assign a new property 'count' with the size of the array
        a[0]['count'] = _.size(a);
        return a[0];
    })
    .map(function(b){...})
    .value();
```