# Grouping by using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var data = [
  {
    "count": 1, 
    "make": "ALFA ROMEO", 
    "model": "GIULIETTA DIESEL - 2010"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 2, 
    "make": "AUDI", 
    "model": "A1 DIESEL"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 1, 
    "make": "AUDI", 
    "model": "A1 SPORTBACK DIESEL"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 2, 
    "make": "AUDI", 
    "model": "A3 DIESEL - 2012"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 3, 
    "make": "Volkswagen", 
    "model": "Golf"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 3, 
    "make": "Ford", 
    "model": "Escord"
  }, 
  {
    "count": 2, 
    "make": "Opel", 
    "model": "Zafira"
  }
]
```

I want to `group by` it by `make` and then get three makes with the highest count and the rest I will to show as other.

For example I want to get:

```
var result = [
    {
       "brand": "Audi",
       "count": 5
     },
     {
       "brand": "Volkswagen",
       "count": 3
     },
     {
       "brand": "Ford",
       "count": 3
     },
     {
       "brand": "Other",
       "count": 3
     }
]
```

I have no idea how to start. Any help?

Comment: _"I have no idea how to start"_ --- are you sure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group or merge this array of objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664213/how-to-group-or-merge-this-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Some good places to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582284/using-underscore-groupby-to-group-an-array-of-cars-by-their-colour and https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744591/underscore-sortby-groupby-with-count-of-grouped-arrays?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using lodash**

Start a lodash chain. Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by the make, then [`_.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the results, and [`_.sumBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) the `count` properties. Convert back to an array using [`_.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), sort descending with [`_.orderBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy), and use `_.value()` to finish the chain. [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the results into 2 arrays, and sum the 2nd array (the lowset counts) using reduce:

```js
var data = [{"count":1,"make":"ALFA ROMEO","model":"GIULIETTA DIESEL - 2010"},{"count":2,"make":"AUDI","model":"A1 DIESEL"},{"count":1,"make":"AUDI","model":"A1 SPORTBACK DIESEL"},{"count":2,"make":"AUDI","model":"A3 DIESEL - 2012"},{"count":3,"make":"Volkswagen","model":"Golf"},{"count":3,"make":"Ford","model":"Escord"},{"count":2,"make":"Opel","model":"Zafira"}];

var counts = _(data)
  .groupBy('make')
  .map(function(g, key) { return {
      make: key,
      count: _.sumBy(g, 'count')
  };})
  .values()
  .orderBy('count', 'desc')
  .value();
  
var result = counts.slice(0, 3).concat({
  brand: 'other',
  count: counts.slice(3).reduce(function(s, { count }) { return s + count; }, 0)
})
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Using ES6**

Iterate with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), collect all the make count values to an object in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), then get the [map values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to get an array, and sort descending. [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the results into 2 arrays, and sum the 2nd array (the lowset counts) using reduce:

```js
const data = [{"count":1,"make":"ALFA ROMEO","model":"GIULIETTA DIESEL - 2010"},{"count":2,"make":"AUDI","model":"A1 DIESEL"},{"count":1,"make":"AUDI","model":"A1 SPORTBACK DIESEL"},{"count":2,"make":"AUDI","model":"A3 DIESEL - 2012"},{"count":3,"make":"Volkswagen","model":"Golf"},{"count":3,"make":"Ford","model":"Escord"},{"count":2,"make":"Opel","model":"Zafira"}];

const counts = [...data.reduce((m, { make, count }) => {
  const item = m.get(make) || { make, count: 0 };
  
  item.count += count;

  return m.set(make,  item);
}, new Map()).values()].sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

const result = counts.slice(0, 3).concat({
  brand: 'other',
  count: counts.slice(3).reduce((s, { count }) => s + count, 0)
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achive that with combination of lodash [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) and [sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sumBy)

```
var result = _.chain(data)
        .groupBy("make")
        .map( (element, id) => ({
            make: id,
            count: _.sumBy(element, 'count'),
        }))
        .value();

console.log(result);

[
  {
    "make": "ALFA ROMEO",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "make": "AUDI",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "make": "Volkswagen",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "make": "Ford",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "make": "Opel",
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain Javascript, you could take a hash table for collecting same `make` and sort the result array. Later add all counts which are at the end of the result set until the array gets a wanted length.

```js
var data = [{ count: 1, make: "ALFA ROMEO", model: "GIULIETTA DIESEL - 2010" }, { count: 2, make: "AUDI", model: "A1 DIESEL" }, { count: 1, make: "AUDI", model: "A1 SPORTBACK DIESEL" }, { count: 2, make: "AUDI", model: "A3 DIESEL - 2012" }, { count: 3, make: "Volkswagen", model: "Golf" }, { count: 3, make: "Ford", model: "Escord" }, { count: 2, make: "Opel", model: "Zafira" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (car) {
    if (!hash[car.make]) {
        hash[car.make] = { make: car.make, count: 0 };
        result.push(hash[car.make]);
    }
    hash[car.make].count += car.count;
});

result.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
});

while (result.length > 4) {
    result.push({ make: 'Other', count: result.pop().count + result.pop().count });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```