# How to create an object with the name and frequency count from an object array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array like this:

```js
const blogs = [
  {
    _id: "5a422a851b54a676234d17f7",
    title: "React patterns",
    author: "Michael Chan",
    url: "https://reactpatterns.com/",
    likes: 7,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb",
    title: "TDD harms architecture",
    author: "Robert C. Martin",
    url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html",
    likes: 0,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc",
    title: "Type wars",
    author: "Robert C. Martin",
    url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html",
    likes: 2,
    __v: 0
  }  
]
```

I want to have at least an object like this:

```js
{
    "name":"Robert C. Martin",
    "blogs": 2,
}
```

I try with lodash but can't understand how I can count the number of blogs for one author.

```js
_.maxBy(blogs, 'author') //gives me the author with the maximum of blogs
_.groupBy(blogs, 'author') // group all blogs in an array under the author name
// _.countBy(blogs,'entries') //that doesn't work
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping by using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415199/grouping-by-using-lodash)

Comment: yes it's the answer using lodash thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to do with plain JavaScript (see [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) if you didnt want to use lodash, for example:

```js
const blogs = [{
    _id: "5a422a851b54a676234d17f7",
    title: "React patterns",
    author: "Michael Chan",
    url: "https://reactpatterns.com/",
    likes: 7,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb",
    title: "TDD harms architecture",
    author: "Robert C. Martin",
    url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html",
    likes: 0,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: "5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc",
    title: "Type wars",
    author: "Robert C. Martin",
    url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html",
    likes: 2,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const blogAuthorCounter = blogs.reduce((obj, blog) => {
  obj[blog.author] = obj[blog.author] ? obj[blog.author] + 1 : 1;

  return obj;
}, {});

Object.entries(blogAuthorCounter).forEach(entry => {
  const [author, count] = entry;

  console.log(`${author} = ${count}`);
});
```

Comment: It need to be a json object as result, I don't understand whinch condition is tested with map.set

Comment: @Sercurio updated to use an object literal instead of a `Map` as per your comment - same idea tho.

Comment: I en dup with the follow:
Object.keys(blogAuthorCounter).reduce((a, b) =>
    blogAuthorCounter[a] > blogAuthorCounter[b]
      ? { author: a, blogs: blogAuthorCounter[a] }
      : { author: b, blogs: blogAuthorCounter[b] },
  )